# Root Mean Square error or Standard Deviation to focus for Machine Learning model selection?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm, model-selection

I have used Linear Regression and Support Vector Machine regressor model to predict the dependent variable.

In Linear regression prediction the Root Mean Square error is more but standard deviation is less compare to Support vector regression result.

*The Root Mean Square Error on predicted value Vs actual value in training data set is 12.83 ( Linear regression)
The Standard Deviation  of the Linear regression evalation is  1.16*

In Support Vector regression result the Root Mean Square error is less but standard deviation is more compare to Linear regression result.

*The Root Mean Square Error on predicted value Vs actual value in training data set is 10.83 ( Support Vector regression)
The Standard Deviation  of the Linear regression evalation is  1.90*

Can you please suggest which parameter to focus more on selecting the model?

Comment: RMSE tells you how much the predictions deviate from the ground truth. But what does it mean to have the standard deviation (SD) here? Of which random variable you've calculated the SD? Do you mean the Standard Error from hypothesis testing instead?

Comment: I have calculated the RMSE and standard deviation RMSE.

Comment: I see. You can use both but for different purposes. RMSE helps to find the optimal coefficients. The SD of the RMSE shows how much the RMSE deviates from its mean. Instead of using the SD directly, I recommend plotting a residual plot to check various things: do the error terms have non-constant variance? is the relationship between the independent and dependent linear? etc.

Comment: The relationship between the independent and dependent is linear with correlation close to 0.9. By plotting the residual plot do you mean plotting a scatter chart of actual and predicted dependent value against the independent variable?

Comment: The residual plot plots the residual/error terms (y_real - y_hat) (y-axis) versus the predictions y_hat (x-axis). Ideally there should be no pattern in the RP. If there is a U-shape pattern, it means there may exist non-linear relationship between the independent and dependent variables. If there is a funnel shape pattern, it hints non-constant variances in the error terms. In linear regression, it is important to ensure that the error terms are uncorrelated and have non-constant variances. So the RP help to detect potential problems in the regression fit.